# How do I programmatically translate a webform?

Tags: 8, webforms, i18n-l10n

Is it possible to add translation for webform programatically in Drupal 8. We have a webform with more than 100 questions and radio options. It is very difficult to manually add translation each time a new translation is provided. So we were thinking of using a CSV file TO programmatically add new translations for the webform, but I could not find a way to do so.

Comment: Here's a hint: Where do you think translations are stored?

Comment: Is it in the database you are mentioning? Or D8 Config Translation?

Comment: that's why it's a hint, I want you to look into it 

Comment: @see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfG37uW5Qu8 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rF8Bd-0w6Cg

Comment: It didn't work out. I tried in many ways. But I couldn't figure out how the translation is added by the webform module. I tried config translation also.